# Pass url from current page to controller in Codeigniter

Tags: php, html, codeigniter

I want to pass my current page url from **views (user/index.php)**, to **controllers (User.php)** because I want to use the url parameter in controllers.

By the way my System has **only one edit page (user/index.php)**, and this page will be use in two different page, the **(views/home.php)** and **(views/faculty/detail.php)**. Each **edit button** in these two pages I made an **href** to direct any of these two pages to edit pages. And at the end of href, I put parameter **eg: edit button for detail.php** `href="<?php echo base_url()?>index.php/user/index/<?php echo $user->user_no ?>?prevpage=index.php/faculty/detail/"` and **user/index.php** will show a url once clicked the edit button `http://[::1]/Test-bank/index.php/user/index/76?prevpage=index.php/faculty/detail/`, And an **edit button for detail.php** `href="<?php echo base_url()?>index.php/user/index/<?php echo $user->user_no ?>?prevpage=index.php/home/"` and **user/index.php** will show a url clicked the edit button `http://[::1]/Test-bank/index.php/user/index/1?prevpage=index.php/home/`.

I want to pass these URL parameter, the `?prevpage=index.php/home/` and `?prevpage=index.php/faculty/detail/` to controllers (User.php) and make it a string in order for me to use it for `redirect(base.url());` so I can **redirect edit page (user/index.php)** back to it **previous page (views/home.php) or (views/faculty/detail.php)**.

(views/home.php)

```
    <div>
         <a href="<?php echo base_url()?>index.php/user/index/<?php echo $user->user_no ? >
          ?prevpage=index.php/home/" class="btn btn-primary">Edit Info</a>
    </div>
```

(views/faculty/detail.php)

```
    <div>
         <a href="<?php echo base_url()?>index.php/user/index/<?php echo $user->user_no ?>
          ?prevpage=index.php/faculty/detail/" class="btn btn-primary">Edit Info</a>
    </div>
```

controllers (User.php)

```
    <?php
       session_start();
       defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

       class User extends CI_Controller {
       function __construct()
     {
       // this is your constructor
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->model('User_Model');
        $this->load->database();
        $this->load->helper('form');
        $this->load->helper('url');
     }

      public function index($user_no = ''){

     if(!isset($_SESSION['authorization'])  || ($_SESSION['authorization'] != '1' && $user_no != 
      $_SESSION['user_no'])){
        redirect(base_url().'index.php','refresh');
        exit();
    }
    $user = $this->User_Model->get_user($user_no);
    $data = array(
        'user'      =>  $user,
    );
    $this->load->view('user/index',$data);
    }

    public function save(){
    $user_no = $this->input->post('user_no') + 0;
    $is_user_full       = $this->User_Model->is_user_full();
    if($is_user_full){
        $_SESSION['result'] = 'ERROR: User List Full';
        redirect(base_url().'index.php/user/index/'.$user_no);
    }
    $is_username_exists = $this->User_Model->check_username($this->input->post('username'));
    if($is_username_exists && $user_no == 0){
        $_SESSION['result'] = 'ERROR: Username Exists';
        redirect(base_url().'index.php/user/index/'.$user_no);
    }
    $data = array(
        'first_name'        =>  $this->input->post('first_name'),
        'last_name'         =>  $this->input->post('last_name'),
        'username'          =>  $this->input->post('username'),
        'authorization'     =>  $this->input->post('authorization') + 0,
    );
    if( !empty($this->input->post('password')) && !empty($this->input->post('cpassword')) ){
        $data['password']   =  $this->input->post('password');
    }
    if($user_no > 0){
        $result = $this->User_Model->update($data,$user_no);
        $redirect = base_url().'******here where I will put the parameter***';

    }
    else{
        $result = $this->User_Model->create($data,$user_no);
        $redirect = base_url().'index.php/faculty/';

    }
    $_SESSION['result'] = ($result) ? 'SUCCESS!' : 'ERROR!';
    redirect($redirect);

    }
```

I don't know what to do there. Hope you could help me.

Comment: If you are talking about `prevpage` then use `$this->input->get('prevpage')`

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to do it.
either use get function to get the parameter you set like this.

```php
$redirect = base_url().$this->input->get('prevpage');
```

or you can use $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] like this to get referrer page url.

Answer (score 0):

Make a hidden input on your view :

```
<?php
    $actual_link                = "0$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]";
?>

<input type="hidden" id="yourID" name="yourName" autocomplete='off' class="form-control" value="<?php echo $actual_link?>">
```

On controller add :

```
$data = array(
    ...
    'thelink'    =>    $this->input->post('yourName'),
    ...
);
```